# How to use session and call from class asp.net mvc 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to use session in asp.net mvc 6 from calling class inside of Iactionresult.

I have class as "**SessionTool** as below"

SessionTool class:

```
public class SessionTool
{
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor;

        public SessionTool(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public void SetSession(string key, string value)
        {
            HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString(key, value);
        }

        public string GetSession(string key)
        {
            return HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString(key);
        }
 }
```

I have **HomeController** as below.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login() 
        {


        SessionTool sessionTool = new SessionTool(IHttpContextAccessor);


        }
}
```

**Question:**

If i try to call SessionTools class as below IHttpContextAccessor displays warning as IHttpContextAccessor is a type , which is not valid in the given context.

```
SessionTool sessionTool = new SessionTool(IHttpContextAccessor);
```

I am new in asp.net mvc 6 and i am not sure how can i set new instance of IHttpContextAccessor to session tool than use session classes ?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use static class for my session helper class. On that helper class I have static properties which return data from session with specific key.
Here is an example of my session structure.

```
  public static class TaskManSession
{
    public static int SelectedProjectId
    {
        get
        {
           if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ProjectId"] ==null)
               {
                 return 0;
               }
            return Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ProjectId"]);
        }
        set
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ProjectId"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

People don't prefer using static classes, because it is hard to use TDD (Test driven development) with static classes. You can read more from [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186218/helper-static-methods-in-tdd)

However "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session" class also has no instance. Therefore I don't see any problem to use a static helper.